# Data race in Java ArrayList class

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading about `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and was wondering how can I demonstrate data race in `ArrayList` class. Basically I'm trying to simulate a situation where `ArrayList` fails so that it becomes necessary to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Any suggestions on how to simulate this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A race is when two (or more) threads try to operate on shared data, and the final output depends on the order the data is accessed (and that order is indeterministic)

From Wikipedia:

> A race condition or race hazard is a flaw in an electronic system or process whereby the output and/or result of the process is unexpectedly and critically dependent on the sequence or timing of other events. The term originates with the idea of two signals racing each other to influence the output first.

For example:

```
public class Test  {
    private static List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        e.execute(new WriterTask());
        e.execute(new WriterTask());
        e.execute(new WriterTask());
        e.execute(new WriterTask());
        e.execute(new WriterTask());

        e.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    static class WriterTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 25000; i ++) {
                list.add("a");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This, however, fails when using `ArrayList`, with `ArrayIndexOutOfbounds`. That's because before insertion the `ensureCapacity(..)` should be called to make sure the internal array can hold the new data. And here's what happens:

- the first thread calls `add(..)`, which in turn calls `ensureCapacity(currentSize + 1)`
- before the first thread has actually incremented the size, the 2nd thread also calls `ensureCapacity(currentSize + 1)`.
- because both have read the initial value of `currentSize`, the new size of the internal array is `currentSize + 1`
- the two threads make the expensive operation to copy the old array into the extended one, with the new size (which *cannot hold both additions*)
- Then each of them tries to assign the new element to `array[size++]`. The first one succeeds, the second one fails, because the internal array has not been expanded properly, due to the rece condition.

This happens, because two threads have tried to add items at the same time on the same structure, and the addition of one of them has overridden the addition of the other (i.e. the first one was lost)

Another benefit of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

- multiple threads write to the `ArrayList`
- a thread iterates the `ArrayList`. It will surely get `ConcurrentModificationException`

Here's how to demonstrate it:

```
public class Test  {
    private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        e.execute(new WriterTask());
        e.execute(new ReaderTask());
    }

    static class ReaderTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                for (String s : list) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class WriterTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                list.add("a");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this program multiple times, you will often be getting `ConcurrentModificationException` *before* you get `OutOfMemoryError`.

If you replace it with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, you don't get the exception (but the program is very slow)

Note that this is just a demonstration - the benefit of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is when the number of reads *vastly outnumbers* the number of writes.

Comment: @Mark - but the question is about multithreading, and this exception (as the name suggest) is inherently "multithreaded".

Comment: Seems like I didn't quite get it. Can you pls tell how data races are caused?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
    Element elm = array.get(i);
    doSomethingWith(elm);
}
```

If another thread calls array.clear() before this thread calls array.get(i), but after it has compared i with array.size(), -> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score -2):

Two threads, one incrementing the arraylist and one decrementing. Data race could happen here.